# Deleted Magento 1,9 database - now get error There has been an error processing your request

Tags: magento-1.9, installation, backup

I am messing with a fresh **magento 1.9** install. I made a backup of my database and had to replace it with the backup.  I used **phpMyAdmin** and deleted all tables and installed them fresh from my backup. I got this error

> There has been an error processing your request
>   Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>   Error log record number:

So I decided to delete all the tables and install it fresh, i thought Magento 1.9 would see it had no tables and run install script again, i get this error

> There has been an error processing your request
>   Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>   Error log record number: 1192419681644

What physical files do I need to edit to

1. Allow me to install my backup SQL
2. Allow me to freshly install 1.9
3. Anything else I may be missing to make this work

Comment: Please turn your debugging on first and/or read 'report' # 1192419681644 in you /var folder. Send us that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start over again but still use an existing sql file, here is what you need to do. Btw, if you didn't delete the Magento site files, you should be able to leave those in place. Run these commands:

//dont type the brackets, just for separation purposes

- echo "DROP DATABASE database_name_here" | mysql -u{username} -p{password}
- echo "CREATE DATABASE database_name_here" | mysql -u{username} -p{password}
- mysql -u{username} -p{password} database_name_here < /path/to/sql/file.sql

Also, double check your `app/etc/local.xml` file and ensure that you have the correct database name, username, and password. Additionally, go to core_config_data table and make sure that you have the correct secure and unsecure urls entered.

Once done, you should be good to go.

Comment: thank you,      ill save this for next time ( i deleted  all and re-installed fresh)

Answer (score 0):

**You need to enable printing errors**

You can enable printing errors to check what problems caused the error. To do this follows these steps:

**Step 1**: go to folder  **Magento/errors**

There you will see  **local.xml.sample**  file, just rename it to  **local.xml** , the purpose of this action is to enable error printing in Magento

**Step 2:** Reload the error page and you will see the full list of error message, this will help you fix the issue

**Or**

Go to `magento/var/report` and open the file with the Error log record number name i.e `1192419681644` in your case. In that file you can find the complete description of the error.

For log files like `system.log` and `exception.log`, go to `magento/var/log/`.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the generated/code directory rm -rf generated/code
Then run

1. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
2. php bin/magento setup:di:compile
3. php bin/magento cache:flush
4. chmo -R 0777 var/ pub/ generated/

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following command on the MySQL console.

```
repair table log_visitor_info;
```

It should fix the problem for you.